# How to remove indentation from the first paragraph after \chapter in twocolumn mode?

Tags: indentation, two-column

Here's the minimal example for my issue:

```tex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

This is a paragraph of text, which is hopefully long enough for the text to wrap on the next line and thus show the paragraph indent problem.

\end{document}
```

When I compile it, it indents the paragraph after `\chapter`, whereas the first paragraph after each `\section`, `\subsection`, etc. is correctly not indented.

How can I disable indentation in this case without manually writing `\noindent` every time? I have tried the `noindentafter` package, but to no avail.

**Edit:** David Carlisle's answer below works well for the minimal example, but breaks with the xcolor package:

```tex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\let\zzchapterhead\@makechapterhead
\def\@makechapterhead#1{\zzchapterhead{#1}\aftergroup\@afterheading}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

This is a paragraph of text, which is hopefully long enough for the text to wrap on the next line and thus show the paragraph indent problem.

\end{document}
```

**Edit 2:** I fixed it with xcolor used by replacing one invocation of `\aftergroup` with seven:

```tex
\makeatletter
\let\zzchapterhead\@makechapterhead
\def\@makechapterhead#1{\zzchapterhead{#1}\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\@afterheading}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 6):

I think that is a bug, although I doubt we can change that after all this time.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}

\makeatletter
\let\zzchapterhead\@makechapterhead
\def\@makechapterhead#1{\zzchapterhead{#1}\aftergroup\@afterheading}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

This is a paragraph of text, which is hopefully long enough for the text to wrap on the next line and thus show the paragraph indent problem.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This solution works fine with the minimal example, however, using the color or xcolor package breaks it, making the first line indented again. Any workaround for those?

Comment: can you add an example to your question (I can't look now I'm in a call, but will look later) @MaiaEverett

Comment: the chapter is in a colorvbox, so with color the code needs to escape two groups.

Comment: Added an example with xcolor that makes the indentation bug reappear for me.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike, I fixed it by including seven \aftergroup commands instead of one.

`\def\@makechapterhead#1{\zzchapterhead{#1}\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\@afterheading}`